# Does a Zealot Barbarian need a God?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities, barbarian

From a standpoint strictly based on the lore of the "default" setting of D&D 5e (or even previous editions, if necessary):

If, for example, an Eldritch Horror from the Far planes were to slaughter all the Gods and destroy the Weave, what would happen to a Zealot's Barbarian Powers?

- Would they lose the "Divine Fury" ability, as there's no god to grant them Divine Energy?
- Would they lose all of their subclass abilities?
- Or would they be able to still use all of their abilities just fine, because "they simply learned to transform their rage into soul-shattering power (a.k.a. radiant damage)".

Again, I'm asking purely from the standpoint of the Lore and Setting. Since 5e is too vague, I'm fine with an anwser based on previous editions as well, like 3.5e

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to ask about a 5e mechanic in the light of 3.5 rules.That doesn't seem kosher, but I'll let the 3.5/lore experts weigh in.

Comment: D&D 3.5e didn’t have “zealot barbarians,” though it had any number of classes with “angry religious” themes. But it’d be really hard to make any apples-to-apples comparisons with them.

Comment: If you're specifically looking for an answer based on 5e or 3.5 then you should leave the 3.5e tag in place. Otherwise, if you're OK with an answer from any edition and merely mentioned 3.5 as an example, you should ditch the 3.5 tag and just use the general D&D tag, which is for questions that are not edition-specific.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like this is opinion-based—the rules don’t even begin to describe what happens if all the gods are destroyed, or even if *your* god is destroyed. Previous editions discussed some of that, but almost-exclusively in the context of clerics and even then it’s not clear how much that would or should apply to 5e since they have explicitly changed at least some of those rules (and not gotten into details on much of the rest). So it really becomes just a matter of opinion how such an unexplored event would play out.

Comment: Are you asking as the DM, or as the Player, in this case?  If you are the DM, do you have and use the DMG?

Answer (score 6):

Homebrew content requires homebrew answers.  Since the D&D rules do not remotely contemplate the utter destruction of the gods (and possibly magic itself, if you're talking about destroying the Weave), it's up to the DM who's running the game to decide how their setting is impacted by such an enormous event.

The Sage Advice compendium gives some advice on how to determine whether a given ability is magical or merely supernatural. Generally, an ability is "magical" if it's a spell (or uses the name of a spell to describe the effect), uses spell slots, or just says it's magical in the description. Everything else is not strictly "magical" for the purpose of game rules, even if it's beyond what we would consider normal physics, such as a ghost's incorporeal existence or a dragon's fiery breath.  But a question like how the death of the gods will impact a specific class feature is outside the scope of anything we can answer. Only your DM can tell you what your DM's world-shaking event does.